# How do i load all of may images in gridview? using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i load all the images of my assets/shirt in Gridview? I have 10 pictures in may assets/shirt

this is my existing code for creating a gridview

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(1, (index) {
          return new Card(
            elevation: 9.0,
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
            child: new Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/shirt/white-shirt1.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),

            ),
          );
          
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
     - assets/shirt/white-shirt1.jpg
     - assets/shirt/yellow-shirt2.jpg
     - assets/shirt/navyblue-shirt3.jpg
     - assets/shirt/blue-shirt4.png
     - assets/shirt/red-shirt5.jpg
     - assets/shirt/brown-shirt6.jpg
     - assets/shirt/maroon-shirt7.jpg
     - assets/shirt/lime-shirt8.jpg
     - assets/shirt/green-shirt9.jpg
     - assets/shirt/gray-shirt10.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pub file not required a file name in the same folder you can you this

```
 assets:
     - assets/shirt/
```

Create a list of the paths:

```
final paths = [
    'assets/shirt/white-shirt1.jpg',
    'assets/shirt/yellow-shirt2.jpg',
    'assets/shirt/navyblue-shirt3.jpg',
    'assets/shirt/blue-shirt4.png',
    'assets/shirt/red-shirt5.jpg',
    'assets/shirt/brown-shirt6.jpg',
    'assets/shirt/maroon-shirt7.jpg',
    'assets/shirt/lime-shirt8.jpg',
    'assets/shirt/green-shirt9.jpg',
    'assets/shirt/gray-shirt10.png'
];
```

Now, instead of List.generate, you can simply use .map on the list.

```
children: paths.map((path) {
    return new Card(
            elevation: 9.0,
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
            child: new Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(path), // Use the path here.
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),

            ),
          );
}).toList(),
```

---

Here is the full code:

```
final paths = [
  'assets/shirt/white-shirt1.jpg',
  'assets/shirt/yellow-shirt2.jpg',
  'assets/shirt/navyblue-shirt3.jpg',
  'assets/shirt/blue-shirt4.png',
  'assets/shirt/red-shirt5.jpg',
  'assets/shirt/brown-shirt6.jpg',
  'assets/shirt/maroon-shirt7.jpg',
  'assets/shirt/lime-shirt8.jpg',
  'assets/shirt/green-shirt9.jpg',
  'assets/shirt/gray-shirt10.png'
];

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
  final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: paths.map((path) {
        return new Card(
          elevation: 9.0,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
          child: new Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(path), // Use the path here.
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: in your `children: paths.map((path) .....` should i paste this inside the  `body: GridView.count`?

Comment: Just change the children property of GridView.count. Replace List.generate with this code :)

Comment: what do you mean? `GridView.count` change to what?